# php composer installing the whole source code and extra files

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm totally new to composer and read the whole manual and started using it, but there is this thing that I can't figure it out.
when I run the command

```
composer require example/example
```

ok, composer downloads the source code of library, but it has downloaded the **WHOLE source code including the samples, readme, test files, anything**. I plan to use many libraries and I don't want extra files to reside on my server.

How can I get rid of extra files composer downloads??

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `--prefer-source` will help you.
`composer require example/example --prefer-source`

Answer (score 0):

Use [--prefer-dist](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) option,

```
composer require example/example --prefer-dist
```

You don't have to use it every time because

> For stable versions Composer will use the dist by default.

Comment: nope, tested with `tracy/tracy` I still get all the extra example files

Comment: You won't get it in another fashion if package vendor designed it that way. It depends on package [exclude](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#archive) settings, but most times the package includes all the files from the repo but VCS-related.

Comment: so there is now way for me to exclude extra files?

Comment: Fork the repo and add `exclude`, or provide installation script to your package and delete junk there, but you will hardly find it is worth the effort. Composer packages aren't that anal regarding extra files as frontend packages, e.g. Bower.